# In Visual Studio is there a way to define a using statement for the whole project? ex. using Random = UnityEngine.Random; for every .cs file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I consistently am dealing with ambiguous references between System.Random and UnityEnginge.Random. To address this I need to add the "using Random = UnityEngine.Random;" to each file. I was curious if instead I could somehow set Random to always use the UnityEngine namespace for the whole project by default.

Manually changing every file seems to be the only solution I could find.

Comment: Yes, [global using directives](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/) do this for you. As long as you're using C# 10 - I don't know what version Unity supports...

Comment: C# 10 added support for a [Global Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier)

Comment: You can also edit the default templates for cs files

Comment: Unity does not support c# 10 so you can't use global using. Always refer to [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html).

Comment: Are you using System.Random with UnityEngine Random in the same class? If not, you may omit the declaration of `using System.Random`. This may be silly but you can create a class that inherits from System.Random within your own namespace and use the class from your namespace in a file that uses both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [global using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive). The global using directive is a new feature that was recently added to C# language in C# version 10.0. This feature allows to declare a namespace globally in any one of the files in a project and the global declared namespace is imported and available to all files in the application

EX:

```
global using System.IO;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for however Unity does not support c# 10 as mentioned by another commenter so I'm afraid this solution will not work for me.